# chrome extension detect ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I currently am developing a chrome extension that allows the user to set up a proxy, however my issue is if the proxy failed to load, chrome returns with `net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED` in the console and a html page that says "Unable to connect to the proxy server". I have been in search of a way to detect this failure to connect so I can restore the connection either with a different proxy or just the normal ip without a proxy. The weird issue is my extensions code does not run on this page.

Am I missing a specific "matches" in the  "content_scripts" in the manifest file thats special to error pages? (even though the url of the error page is the url for the page I am trying to visit and the extension code runs on if there is a working proxy/connection)

Is there a way to catch this error? Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is how I set up the proxy But as a reminder this code works, the issue is if you try connecting to a proxy server that isn't available, the browser just shuts down and my extensions code is not longer run with the page.

```
    var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: "http",
                host: request.ip
            }
        }
    };
    chrome.proxy.settings.set({
        value: config,
        scope: 'regular'
    }, function() {});
```

My manifest code: (which runs as it should until the proxy fails)

```
"content_scripts": [ {
"js": [ "jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "myscript.js" ],
"matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*","http://*/"],
"run_at": "document_end"
},
```

And a picture of the error page chrome returns when the proxy is not reachable:
[image]

Comment: You have to show some code and mention which proxy backend you're using. With the lack of details in the current question, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will add some code, but my question is more of a how can i do this not a what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to support multiple proxies, just use a [PAC script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) and specify the fallback, as in the following example (upon failure to connect to `proxy1:80`, `proxy2:8080` is tried, and if that fails as well, then Chrome will attempt a direct connection because of `"DIRECT"`).

```js
var config = {
    mode: 'pac_script',
    pacScript: {
        data: 'function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {\n' +
              '    if (url.substring(0, 5) == "http:")\n' +
              '        return "PROXY proxy1:80; PROXY proxy2:8080; DIRECT";\n' +
              '    return "DIRECT";\n' +
              '}'
    }
};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({
    value: config,
    scope: 'regular'
}, function() {
});
```